# SSRS Assign a Value in dataset 2 based on a value in dataset1

Tags: reporting-services, dataset, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have an SSRS report with 2 datasets. *dataset1* has a value called `Party_Number` and *dataset2* has a value called `Name`.

I am pulling the name from a Lookup:

```
Lookup(Fields!MODIFIED_IPP.Value,Fields!IPP.Value,Fields!Trustee_Name.Value,"DataSet2")
```

However I want to hard code 2 values because the IPPs do not exist in dataset1.

For example I would like to say `IIF` the `IPP` in *dataset1* equals 111 then use the name *"Jane Doe"* for `Trustee_Name` else use the above Lookup expression.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following expression, it has multiple `iif` with lookups. The first two `iif` are hard coded to the values of `111` and `222`, then a lookup and a blank default entry if nothing is detected.

Hope this helps some...

```
=IIF(Fields!MODIFIED_IPP.Value = "111", "Jane Doe",IIF(Fields!MODIFIED_IPP.Value = "222", "John Dex",
 IIF(len(Lookup(Fields!MODIFIED_IPP.Value, Fields!IPP.Value,  Fields!Trustee_Name.Value, "DataSet2")) > 0 , 
 Lookup(Fields!MODIFIED_IPP.Value, Fields!IPP.Value,  Fields!Trustee_Name.Value, "DataSet2") , "Blank default entry")))
```

Comment: Thanks Philip.  This hard codes the MODIFIED_IPP but what I am trying to do is hardcode the TRUST_NAME.  For example, if the MODIFIED_IPP from dataset1 is 222 I want the TRUST_NAME in dataset2 to equal "John Dex".  It looks like the above is saying is the MODIFIED_IPP is 222 then make the MODIFIED_IPP "John Dex".